# Hamming Distance using Recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have an assignment that requires me to write a Java program that uses recursion to solve the Hamming distance for a string bit. For example, A string bit of "010010" with a distance of 1 will produce "110010 000010 011010 010110 010000 010011". Each bit is "1" bit differently from the given string of 010010. The bit string and the integer k are command line arguments for my program and passed through the method displayAllAtDistance(String s, int k).

I'm fairly new to recursion so I've been trying out a lot of different designs but can't seem to get anywhere. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class Hamming {
    public static void displayAllAtDistance(String s, int k) {
        displayAllAtDistance(0, s, k, s.length());   
    }

    public static void displayAllAtDistance(int position, String bit, int k, int length) {
        // Base Case that will print the bits when the distance reaches 0
        if (k == 0) {
            System.out.print(bit);
            return;
        }
        // Inductive step
        if (k >= 1) {
            // For the recursive part, I don't exactly know what I want to type here.
            // I want to change the digits of the bit I get by the distance, k, then print it
            // and continue on to with the original bit by calling the recursive function again?

            if (bit.charAt(position) == '0')) {
                displayAllAtDistance(position + 1, bit, k - 1, length);
            } else if(bit.charAt(position == '1')) {
                displayAllAtDistance(position + 1, bit, k - 1, length);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the upper and lower bound of the range 
        String bits = args[0];
        int distance = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        displayAllAtDistance(bits, distance);
  }
}
```

Comment: The key may be to note that 1) it is easy to produce all the bitstrings that are a distance of 1 from a given bitstring, and 2) a bitstring that is a distance k, k>1 from a given string is just really a bitstring that is a distance of 1 from another bitstring that is a distance of k-1 from the original string.

Comment: when k = position then flip the bit